# problem after suspend ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I'd like to have a thing cleared.
I just started using Ubuntu and installed 12.04 the only problem is that when i turn my laptop back on after suspension i get a black screen with this written:

```
legacy_resume():pnp_bus_resume+0x0/0x70 return -19
PM: Device 00:09 failed to resume: error -19
i8042: Can't reactivate AUX port
```

and after this message at times my touchpad doesn't work as well.
I am currently using a vpc eh2n1e
thanks for the support

Comment: pertinent thread (with similar error description but no solution as yet): http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=679231 and also http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1966695

Comment: "Sleep & Resume works fine [from a clean boot]. **Following a couple of sleeps**, however, [the machine gets cranky](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=679231)." Cranky, in my case, means powering-off (physically **pulling the plug**). This has happened _twice_ already (just now and some time last week). Attempting a tty-rescue would also not work, as the tty-1 session would freeze, too! Very disconcerting! :-(

Comment: Do you get past the error message(s) or does your system freeze upon resume (so that you need to physically power-off, as well) ?

Comment: In my case this *might* (unfortunately) be a recent hardware issue, with the following message coming up on boot: `0200: Failure Fixed Disk 1` on my venerable IBM Thinkpad X41 ... :-(

Answer (score 0):

According to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libcgroup/+bug/838729) it could be due to a bug causing a race condition in `libcgroups`.

Try this from a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install cgroup-lite

sudo apt-get remove cgroup-bin
```

Comment: sorry but this didn't work....

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here buddy, it might help -

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978290

Cheers ;)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.